# Web3: Does contract.methods.transfer().send({}).on('error') ever get fired, but the transaction was still successful?

Tags: web3js, transactions, error

I have some web3 code that calls the method `transfer` on an ERC20 contract

```
                let result = await contract.methods.transfer(r.fromaddress, truncatedAmount).send({
                    from: myAddress, 
                    gas: web3instance.utils.toHex(gasEstimate),
                    gasPrice: web3instance.utils.toHex(gasPrice),
                    chainId: chainIdHex,
                    txHash: r.txhash,
                    nonce: nonce++,
                    
                })
                .on('transactionHash', function(hash){
                    console.log('transaction hash for: '+r.fromaddress+' for the amount: '+truncatedAmount+" is: "+hash);
                })
                .on('error', function(error)
                {
                    console.log('THERE WAS AN ERROR!!!!!!!!!');
                    console.log(error);
                    nonce--;
                })
```

Is there any instance where the `.on('error', function(){})` code will be executed, despite the transaction being accepted on the blockchain? In other words, are there are error codes that don't make the transaction fail?